# How to add number from file to variable?

Tags: python-3.x

I have file:

```
0 3 0.071       0.082       0.002
0 4 144         145.5       0.2
0 6 0.36        0.46        0.02
```

and I would like to add some number to variable. How to do that? I know how to add a column to variable. Is it possible by using table?

This is code to add column ti variable, but I don't know how to add one number to variable.

```
x = np.loadtxt('file', unpack=True, usecols=[1])
```

Comment: Does your code not work? If so, please describe the issue.

Comment: This code works for adding column to variable, but I don't know how to add one number from file

Comment: You can retrieve individual elements from the array `x` via [indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html).